# can someone explain how my random code works in python for rock, paper, scissors?

Tags: random, import

can someone please explain how this random code works. my teacher wont let me use it unless it can be explained.
the code works perfectly but i dont know how it works.

```
import random
pick = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
print  (pick[int(random.random() * len(pick))])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to understand if you do it line by line

Import a class that can generate random values

```
import random
```

Create an array variable that contains the choices

```
pick = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors']
```

Get length of array 'pick'

```
lengthOfArray = len(pick)
```

Get random number using the function 'random' from the class 'random' we imported earlier

```
randomNumber = random.random()
```

This gives us a randomNumber which will equal some value between 0.00 to 1.00

We then multiply this by the total length of the array which gives us another value

```
randomTimesLength = randomNumber * lengthOfArray
```

This will give us a float somewhere between 0.00 and 3.00 by using an int function, we round this down to the nearest integer. It's important to note that we're rounding DOWN so our final integer will be either 0, 1, or 2 because in arrays, indexes begin at 0 but object counts begin with 1.

```
randomInteger = int(randomTimesLength)
```

Then we get the object from our 'pick' array that is listed at the index of our randomInteger

```
choice = pick[randomInteger]
```

Then we print the choice

```
print (choice)
```

Or you could combine all of these steps into one line as you've done above.  Basically,

This:

```
import random

# This  
pick = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors'] 
print (pick[int(random.random() * len(pick))])

# Is Equal To This
pick = ['Rock','Paper','Scissors'] 
lengthOfArray = len(pick)
randomNumber = random.random()
randomTimesLength = randomNumber * lengthOfArray
randomInteger = int(randomTimesLength)
choice = pick[randomInteger]
print (choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the key line here is

```
print  (pick[int(random.random() * len(pick))])
```

We can break that down. First, random.random() generates a random floating-point number between 0.0 and 1.0. Next, len(pick) returns the length of the array named pick, which is 3. So the value of random.random() * len(pick) will be between 0.0 and 3.0.

Next, it calls the int() function on that value. The int function turns an input value into an integer; when the input value is a floating point number, it rounds that value down to get the integer. So 0.0 through 0.9999999... turn into 0, 1.0 through 1.999999... turn into 1, and so on. Thus, you end up with 0, 1, or 2.(1) Then it calls pick[] with that value, which returns one of the three strings.

(1) I'm pretty sure there's a bug in this code when the random.random() generates 1.0, which gets multiplied to 3.0, which rounds down to 3, but that would happen very rarely.

Comment: There's no bug, because according to the documentation `random.random()` returns a value in the range `[0,1)`. In other words, it can produce zeros but it will never produce a one, and therefore, when scaled, it will never produce a three.